# working with odd bit sized unions

Tags: c++, byte, bit

I am trying to build RTCM SC104 v3 messages. This standard requires only using the minumum number of bits to transmit the data to the maximum defined range it can be. So to join the data I was going to use unions. But how to you joint odd sized unions to the previous odd sized union? For instance message 1002 requires 74 bits for each satelite. There are no padding bits untill the message is complete with all of the data for n number of satelites in view. Can I just build a union of the previous unions?

```
 typedef union headerGPS
    {
    struct
    {
    unsigned int  msgNo    :12; // creates a 12 bit wide integral field
    unsigned int  baseID   :12; //base index number
    unsigned int  tow      :30; //time of measurement
    unsigned int  syncFlg  :1;  //1 if all GNSS readings same time
    unsigned int  no_gps   :5;  //number of gps readings
    unsigned int smoothInd :1;  //smoothing indicator
    unsigned int smoothInt :3;  //smoothing int rep
    } fields;
    unsigned char header[8];
} headerGPS;
typedef union data1002
{
    struct            //74 bits / 9.25 bytes per SV
    {
    INT8U      satID   :6;  //sat ID 6 bit
    INT8U      L1ind   :1;  //L1 indicator 1 bit set 1
    INT32U     L1range :24; //L1 psuedorange uint24
    int        diff    :20; //L1 phaserange - psuedorange int20
    INT8U      lockInd :7;  //L1 locktime indicator uint7
    INT8U      ambi    :8;  //L1 int ambiguity uint8
    INT8U      cnr     :8;  //L1 CNR uint8
    }fields;
    INT8U data[];
}data1002;

bool encode1002( int baseNumber, int gpsEpoch , int numberGpsSV, int numberGloSV, int  numberGalSV )
{
    std::string message1002;
    headerGPS h1002; //create header object
    h1002.fields.msgNo = 1002;
    h1002.fields.baseID = baseNumber;
    h1002.fields.tow = gpsEpoch;
    if(numberGloSV > 0 || numberGalSV > 0)
    {
        h1002.fields.syncFlg = 1;
    }
    else
   {
        h1002.fields.syncFlg = 0;
    }

    h1002.fields.no_gps = numberGpsSV;
    h1002.fields.smoothInd = 0;
    h1002.fields.smoothInt = 0;
    for(int n=0; n<8; n++)
    {
        message1002 += h1002.header[n];
    }//1002 header is complete







return true;
}
```

OK so I am trying to setup a bitset to prepare the data to send out. I am using this kind of staement to fill the bitset in the needed order without extra filler bits being added. This is in a "for" statement and an "if channel data good" statement.

```
for(varPos = 0; varPos < 6; varPos ++) //start on 0, end on 5
        {
            data_1002.set(bitPos,datastream[baseNumber].channel[n].satID & (1<<varPos)); //test bit
            bitPos++;
        }
        data_1002.set(bitPos,1);
        bitPos++;
        for(varPos = 0; varPos < 24; varPos ++) //start on 0, end on 5
        {
            data_1002.set(bitPos,codeRange & (1<<varPos)); //test bit
            bitPos++;
        }
```

I want to copy all of the bit values from the bitset to an array of bytes to send out TCP/IP port using the following:

```
int noBytes = (bitPos+7)/8; //number of data bytes to copy to array
if(noBytes <=0)
{
    noBytes = 0;
}
cout << "number of bytes to process=  " << noBytes <<endl;
cout <<"completed bitset size= " << bitPos << endl;

//convert bits to bytes

bitPos = 0;
int byteCount;
for (int w=0; w<noBytes; w++)  //bitPos/8 = number of bytes; w+8 because 8 bytes in header
{
    for(int q=0; q<8; q++)
    {
        if(data_1002.test(bitPos+q) == 1)
        {
            BUFFER[(w+8)] = BUFFER[(w+8)] | (1<<q);
        }
        else
        {
            BUFFER[(w+8)] = BUFFER[(w+8)] & (0xFF & (0<<q));
        }
    }
    bitPos = bitPos +8;
    byteCount = w+8;
}
cout << "bytecounter=  " << byteCount << endl;
cout<<"number btes processed plus header=  "<< noBytes+8 <<endl;
for(int w=0; w<noBytes+8; w++)
{
   output += BUFFER[w];
}
```

This seems like it should be working however if I am missing a mistake in the coding of this I would appreciate any help. also is there no easier way to transfer a bitset into a byte array to send out? I read up and tried inserting a bitset in a stringstream but it inserts each bit as a char instead of a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you wanted to join the data by making another *union* of the odd sized structs?  This would result in the 2 odd sized structs referring to the same binary data.  I think what you wanted was to append, like to make a new struct with the 2 unions in it; and what you wanted was them to be sandwiched together with no padding bits?

Bit packed structs of odd size will always be aligned, either by byte, word, or whatever the compiler chooses.  If you place two of these in another struct, they will be padded.  You'll have to go about it a different way.

So, why not just put all of the declarations packed into one struct?  maybe because you have multiple appearances of headerGPS and data1002?  If so one solution could be: (as much as I find preprocessor macros to be a hack, sometimes it's the only way).

```
#define headerGPS(n) \
        unsigned int  msgNo_##n    :12; \
        unsigned int  baseID_##n   :12; \
        unsigned int  tow_##n      :30; \
        unsigned int  syncFlg_##n  :1;  \
        unsigned int  no_gps_##n   :5;  \
        unsigned int smoothInd_##n :1;  \
        unsigned int smoothInt_##n :3

#define data1002(n) \
        INT8U      satID_##n   :6; \
        INT8U      L1ind_##n   :1; \
        INT32U     L1range_##n :24;\
        int        diff_##n    :20;\
        INT8U      lockInd_##n :7; \
        INT8U      ambi_##n    :8; \
        INT8U      cnr_##n     :8

union gpsdata {
    struct {
    headerGPS(1);
    data1002(1);
    data1002(2);
    };
    INT8U data[];
};
```

Note the usage of the append operator `##`, so you can add unique extensions so the names become `satID_1` and `satID_2`.

This solution is a bit of a hack though, it may confuse your IDE parser; Eclipse did correctly suggested members for me when I tested.

Comment: I'm working in codeblocks. I need 1 headerGPS but a variable number of data1002 structures depending on the number of GPS sv's in view at the time. I was going to try making one giant structure with space for up to 15 sv's but when there are say 7 in view the rest of the structure is full of zero's. So I'm wondering if the way you showed would be able to enter n sv's at run time and only append the number of data structures as needed? Then by default would the last bits in the number of bytes (being windows os the MSB) needed to hold it be set to 0's? This would in theory would do what I need.

Comment: You can not do this at run time.  Going back to your original task, if you are just trying to make the compiler parse the GPS string for you, Speed8ump is right; I wouldn't count on C/C++ structure formating; much better to bit bash yourself.  Check out Sean Eron Anderson's page http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't like dealing with data that isn't byte aligned specifically because there's no really good way to manage it in C.  That being said, I wouldn't do the macro magic described elsewhere because, hey, this is tagged C++!

Try this instead:

```
template< class ValueT, int OffsetV, int BitsV >
class BitfieldAt
{
   typedef ValueT ValueType;
   static const int Offset = OffsetV;
   static const int Bits = BitsV;
   static const int Mask = (1<<Bits) - 1;

   //do a static assert that sizeof(ValueType)<<3 >= BitsV + 7
};

template< int BitLength >
class BitStruct
{
   template< class Field >
   inline Type fetch( int index )
   {
      unsigned int offset = index * BitLength + Field::Offset;

      //find offset into memory, pull up value that is too large;
      ValueType retVal = (*(Field::ValueType *)(&((UInt8 *)this)[offset >> 3]));

      //shift it, then mask it
      return (retVal >> (offset & 0x07)) & Field::Mask;
   }

   //create explicit specialization for fetch<BoolFieldAt>
}
```

Used like this:

```
//define the fields, their bit offsets and bit widths
typedef BitFieldAt<UInt16,0,6> satID;
typedef BitFieldAt<UInt8,6,1>  L1ind;

//demonstrate how to lookup some element
void Foo( BitStruct *dataBlock )
{
   if ( dataBlock->fetch<satID>(3) == 0x05 )
```

This should optimize down to nearly nothing (a multiply, an array offset, a bit shift, and a bitwise and.  If you know the index at compile time you could also add an alternate member template:

```
   if ( dataBlock->fetch<satID,3>() == 0x05 )
```

This eliminates the multiply and should allow the compiler to statically define the array index and the shift.

Anyway, that's *a* way.

Comment: This example is going to take me a while to digest. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, I was just illustrating a way to have the template system manage the bit shifting and offset management.  That way the compiler can optimize where feasible.  Good luck.